# MathJax and iPhone Objective C

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, mathjax

I am trying to use MathJax in my iPhone app that I am building. I currently have both MathJax and the unpacked version of MathJax in my Resources folder. I have a html file in my Resources folder that is a direct copy of the sample.html file in the MathJax test folder. I then have a view that loads and when it does loads data into a UIWebView.

When the view loads it gets the data from the file like this:

```
NSString *htmlText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The File path is retrieved by doing the following: `NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"SSS" ofType:@"html"];

Then I have the MathJax folders in my resource folders and do have them setup so that they are listed under Copy Bundle Resources not Compile Sources in the Build Phases.

Once I have the htmlText in the string. I go to load the data in the UIWebView. I do this the following way:

```
[htmlView loadHTMLString:htmlText baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

The webpage loads into the UIWebView but none of the LaTex is rendered correctly. When I load the sample.html page within the MathJax folder it loads correctly, so I know that I have that setup right. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
NSString *basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                       pathForResource:@"htmlFileName" ofType:@"html" 
                       inDirectory:@"."];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

This way relative paths will be used properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new post about using MathJax v1.1a locally [here](http://new2objectivec.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/tutorial-how-to-setup-mathjax-locally.html). Davide have suggested some further improvements which I haven't got time to try yet, but the existing code should help with your problem, hope this helps.